# Multiple IP addresses on Network Card Win2003

Tags: networking, windows-server-2003, ip-address

When I add the additional addresses on a network interface in Windows 2003 Server Enterprise Edition, starting from 2800 addresses there are some problems:

1. Icons do not create, delete or copy from the desktop by explorer.
2. Internet Explorer does not run.
3. Event Viewer is not right. When i try to open event, it does not open.

And many others. These symptoms appear when I remove all addresses.

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Voting to close, and noting that having 2,800 IP addresses on a single interface sounds insane to me. But I'm just a programmer, so what do I know.

Comment: Why in the hell would you have 2800 IP addresses on one NIC?

Comment: I think you mean the symptoms *dis*appear when you remove all addresses, to which I reply, "As they should."  Frankly I'm surprised a black hole hasn't opened up and swallowed up the NIC and the surrounding server room.

Answer (score 7):

What you're trying to do is...let's be polite about this...a design issue.

Basically there's literally no reason to do this, I'd be surprised if Windows let you add more than about 128/256 interfaces before falling over.

You need to think about what you're trying to achieve here and design your solution using the right tools; i.e. routers, L3-switches, load-balancers and at some point servers - not just trying to do what you've tried, that won't work.

Answer (score 3):

You can fix the problem by not assigning 2,800 IPs to a single NIC.  I can think of no logical reason to do that.

EDIT:

I apologize if my answer sounds harsh.  You are only setting yourself up for failures by trying to add that many IPs to a single NIC.  In Windows Server 2000 there was a limitation on how many IPs you could add using the GUI.  In Windows Server 2003 this limitation was removed.  However, adding that many IPs would have a negative effect on resources.  Not to mention, it would be a management nightmare.  Imagine a new sysadmin logging into that server not knowing that many IPs were added and resetting the NIC to use DHCP (I've seen this happen).  All 2800 of your IPs are now gone.

As Chopper advised, your better option is to re-evaluate what you are trying to do and figure out another option.